# Cloud FireStore schema for Social Newsfeed in Flutter

Tags: firebase, database-design, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have referred on the below sites for getting ideas on better Firebase schema design for a social network application.

- https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html
- [Firebase fan-out structure for news feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45100384/firebase-fan-out-structure-for-news-feed)
- https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/
- https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data

But I fail to understand the recent developments and features available in Cloud FireStore of Firebase.

I have below requirements to be store.

1. To Store Image Upload
2. Comments for the Image
3. Likes activity
4. User following activity

I should be able to get them individually or all activities in a single call. How best can I organize the data model?

All the above is present in the below example. But I have question on getting all types of activities to show the master news feed in a single call sorted by time.

https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix/blob/master/design.md

PS: I will be using it with Flutter.

Other models discussed: [Firestore - how to structure a feed and follow system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979375/firestore-how-to-structure-a-feed-and-follow-system)

Comment: Did you have any luck? :-)

Comment: No. not yet. I am trying out my own structure which I am not comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

[This Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/share/101ym6AksfdlZbRnQ=/) gives a very good idea about how to design a fanned-out social media DB. However, it doesn't implement the "fanoutObject" concept mentioned in [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html?m=1) blog. It is updating each duplicate collections independently. So not sure how consistency is guaranteed.